# JavaScript - Order of div's where the top one is not affected by onclick scripts from below divs

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have three div boxes that stack on top of each other so that one is closer than the background div. However the background div has this event handler: onclick="hideLarge();"

The issue is that when I click on the div box at the front even though it is blocking the visibility of the background div, it still triggers that onclick function which I do not want it to do.

Is there a way that the front div box can intercept these?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DOM structure is like so:

```
Document
 |- BODY
     |- DIV(#1)
         |- DIV(#2)
         |- DIV(#3)
             |- DIV(#4)
             |- DIV(#5)
```

Then clicks on #4,#5 will bubble up to #3 and #1 while clicks on #3 and #2 will bubble to #1.

If you on the other hand have a stucture like this:

```
Document
 |- BODY
     |- DIV(#1)
     |- DIV(#2)
     |- DIV(#3)
     |- DIV(#4)
     |- DIV(#5)
```

None of the divs will bobble to other then document.body and document.

You can use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling up. Say we bind a click listener on #5 in example 1:

```
div5.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

The event will be stopped before it reaches div #3 and therefore also not reach #1.

If you have multiply click event bound on #5 these will not be stopped. If you wish to stop these you should use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Note that some versions of IE have a different way of doing this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Thank you both. The event.stopPropagation(); worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the clicked div is background div or not like,
Here top div is the id of the div of top one

```
function hideLarge(evt) {
if(evt.target.id!='top_div'){
//code
}
```